# Alternative or workaround to OrderedDictionary to avoid duplicate key error

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using a function to return an OrderedDictionary and populate a section of a pdf but I need to include duplicate keys as they are label texts. Is there a way to mask the dupes or a better way to do this which isn't fussy about the dupes?

```
    Private Shared Async Function GetSiteSpecificStaging(MDTID As String, Optional cSite As String = Nothing) As Task(Of OrderedDictionary(Of String, String))
            Using con = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString),
                com = con.CreateCommand
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                com.CommandText = "GetPrintStagingData"
                com.CommandTimeout = 600
                con.Open()
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MDTID", MDTID)

                Using r = Await com.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)
                    If r.Read Then
                        Return New OrderedDictionary(Of String, String) From {
                            {"Reported Date", r("StageReportDate1").ToString.NullIfNotDate?.ToShortDateString},
                            {"Reporting Organisation", r("StageReportOrg1").ToString},
                            {"Chang Stage", r("Chang").ToString},
                            {"INRG Staging System", r("INRG_DESC").ToString},
                            {"Biopsy Gleason", FormatGleason(r("BiopsyGleason1").ToString, r("BiopsyGleason2").ToString)},
                            {"Reported Date", r("StageReportDate2").ToString},
                            {"Reporting Organisation", r("StageReportOrg2").ToString}
                        }
                    Else
                        Return New OrderedDictionary(Of String, String)
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Function
```

Comment: Use a `List(Of Class)` + `OrderBy()`?

Comment: @Jimi ok thanks, i'll give it a shot!